# Logarithm of a bounded operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-exponential

Let $\mathbb H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb H)$ such that the spectrum of $A$ does not meet a closed half-line issued from 0 in the complex plane. Then I guess that
$
A=\exp L
$
where $L\in \mathcal B(\mathbb H)$.

**Question 1.** Is there a reference for this result?

**Question 2.** Is there a Banach space version?

Comment: A simple counterexample is the sequence $(\frac 1n)$ (regarded as a multiplication operator on $\ell^2$).  What you require is  that the spectrum be contained in a set on which the logarithm function is bounded (i.e. bounded away from $0$).

Comment: @terceira Doesn't the spectrum of your operator contain $0$, and therefore violate the condition about not meeting a half-line issued from $0$?

Comment: @Nik Weaver. Yes, you're right,of course. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

The other answer is not correct. If $L$ is the half-line issuing from the origin, then we can find a branch of the logarithm that is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus L \supset{\rm spec}(A)$. Then applying the holomorphic functional calculus to $A$ yields the desired operator $B$ with $e^B = A$. And yes, this holds for Banach space operators too (one has holomorphic functional calculus in every Banach algebra).

Comment: Essentially, I aggree. I was fooled by the ambiguity of the question. It mentions a half-line, which could be open (my answer) or closed (yours).

Comment: (The other answer I referred to has been deleted.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Banach algebra version of the result (including the Banach space version) in Theorem 10.30 (page 264) of W. Rudin's book Functional analysis, 2nd ed. McGraw-Hill 1991.

Comment: One of my all time favorite books.